# Swift table view Embedded in Container

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have an NSManagedObject that is being used in my main view.

in this view I have two containers, each with their own static TableViews going on.

In my NSManagedObject I have an array I'd like to loop over, and display info on the screen like so:

```
Customer1 Name
Customer1 Type
Customer1 Address

Customer2 Name
Customer2 Type
Customer2 Address
```

I have tried to go the route of using a TableView, I have added a container, embedded the tableview in it, set a custom cell and tried to populate the custom cell with some test data. When I run it though the TableView just shows the four empty rows. (I'm probably missing something to do with the amount of rows which is why my test data isn't showing):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell =  self.tblPartyDetails.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        "JobViewPartyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        as! JobViewPartyCell

    cell.lblPartyName.text = "test name"
    cell.lblPartyAddress.text = "test adddress"

    cell.lblPartyType.text = "test partyType"

    return cell
}
```

I also have to figure out how to pass my NSManagedObject into this TableView class and it seems like a lot of effort for what is just a repeated block of information...or...is this the only way to do it?

So, am I going about this in the right way? If so, how do I fix it and add my NSManagedObjects details to the TableView. If I'm not going about this correctly, what are the alternatives? I had a look at some other custom 'card' type stuff, like facebook and google cards, but those techniques use custom TableViewCells as well.

edit. PrepareForSegue function:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == jobSegueIdentifier {


        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? JobViewController {
                            if let jobIndex = tblJobs.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
                                 let workItem:Work = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(jobIndex) as! Work
                                destination.workItem = workItem

                            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you returned 0 in your `numberOfRowsInSection` and what you should do is putting the number of rows you want to display, if your are testing your tableView put any number.

And if your data is in your mainView you should pass your data to the contained tableView so you can display it and in your number of rows you should return the number of elements in your data array.

First give an identifier to your embed segue in the storyboard and in your main view implement the prepareForSegue function as follows:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "embedSegueIdentifier" {

        let distinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? EmbeddedTableViewController //replace EmbeddedTableViewController with your tableViewControllerClass

        distinationVC?.dataArray = yourDataArray //yourDataArray is in your main view and you should define data array in your embedded table view controller

    }

}
```

and in your tableViewController add the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return dataArray.count

}
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am already passing the object to a view controller, the tableview is embedded in that controller, I've updated my post with the prepareForSegue function.