# Delegation not working in swift with subview

Tags: swift, uitableview, subview

Edit: someone suggested this was a duplicate of another question.  It is not I have implemented:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section //(in swift of course).
```

In a ViewController I programmatically create a tableView and add it as a subview.  I have a class named DataSource that adopts UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource via two extensions.

I'm following an example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319029/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-reusable-tableview-for-different-screens-in-the-s)

I'm getting an error:

> ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f88cc406ac0'

0x7f88cc406ac0 is the address of the containing ViewController.

Even if I make the containing ViewController adopt UITableViewDelegate via an extension and then that calls the DataSource implementation of tableView:numberOfRowsInSection I still see the error.

Ideas?

```
import UIKit

class GenericDataSource: NSObject {
    let identifier     = "cell"
    var array: [Any]   = ["Dogs","Cats","Mice"]

    func registerCells(forTableView tableView: UITableView) {
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
//        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }

    func loadCell(atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath, forTableView tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell {
//        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

        let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel!.text = array [indexPath.row] as? String
        return cell
    }
}

// UITableViewDataSource
extension GenericDataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return self.loadCell(atIndexPath: indexPath, forTableView: tableView)
    }

}
// UITableViewDelegate
extension GenericDataSource: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)      {

    }
}
protocol GenericDataSourceDelegate: class {
    // Delegate callbacks methods
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.dataSource.numberOfSections(in: tableView)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.tableView(tableView,numberOfRowsInSection:section)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return dataSource.tableView(tableView,cellForRowAt:indexPath)
    }
}

func requestTableView() -> UITableView {
    return UITableView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var tableView: UITableView?
    var dataSource = GenericDataSource()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView = requestTableView()

        if(tableView != nil) {
            self.tableView!.delegate      =   self
            self.tableView!.dataSource    =   dataSource
            self.view.addSubview(self.tableView!)
        }
    }
}
```

As requested here is the entire error message:

> 2018-03-09 08:37:52.479763-0800 Job[3560:6187366] -[Job.ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9164c065b0
>   2018-03-09 08:37:52.623521-0800 Job[3560:6187366] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Job.ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9164c065b0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001089fc12b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104d08f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108a7d024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
>       3   UIKit                               0x00000001057d8f51 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 295
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010897ef78 ___forwarding_** + 1432
>       5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010897e958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       6   UIKit                               0x0000000105713b4c -[UITableView _numberOfRowsInSection:] + 62
>       7   UIKit                               0x00000001059c60e1 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 2389
>       8   UIKit                               0x00000001059cc5ab -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 487
>       9   UIKit                               0x00000001059cc711 -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 61
>       10  UIKit                               0x00000001056c1a65 -[UITableView _updateContentSize] + 372
>       11  UIKit                               0x00000001056f267d -[UITableView _rebuildGeometry] + 66
>       12  UIKit                               0x00000001056f003c -[UITableView didMoveToWindow] + 145
>       13  UIKit                               0x000000010566d147 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1748
>       14  UIKit                               0x0000000105686a81 -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 84
>       15  UIKit                               0x000000010565f1e1 **45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 151
>       16  UIKit                               0x000000010565f0c8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 828
>       17  UIKit                               0x000000010566fcbd -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1973
>       18  UIKit                               0x0000000105618aa2 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 845
>       19  UIKit                               0x0000000105618ed7 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294
>       20  UIKit                               0x000000010562be54 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
>       21  UIKit                               0x000000010559e8b8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4737
>       22  UIKit                               0x00000001055a3aeb -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1720
>       23  UIKit                               0x000000010596d6f8 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 924
>       24  UIKit                               0x0000000105d434c8 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
>       25  UIKit                               0x000000010596d2f1 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 249
>       26  UIKit                               0x000000010596db6b -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 696
>       27  UIKit                               0x00000001062eba69 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 262
>       28  UIKit                               0x00000001062eb922 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 444
>       29  UIKit                               0x0000000105fc89c8 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 221
>       30  UIKit                               0x00000001061c7b06 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
>       31  UIKit                               0x0000000105fc888b -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 231
>       32  UIKit                               0x0000000105d42b25 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
>       33  UIKit                               0x00000001055a236a -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 523
>       34  UIKit                               0x0000000105b7d605 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 369
>       35  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a8bfcc0 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 338
>       36  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a8c87b5 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 235
>       37  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109b1e33d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       38  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109b239f3 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
>       39  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a8f4498 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24
>       40  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a8f414e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 464
>       41  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a8f46bd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
>       42  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010899f101 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       43  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108a3ef71 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
>       44  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108983a19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
>       45  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108982fff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
>       46  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108982889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
>       47  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b1889c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
>       48  UIKit                               0x00000001055a55d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       49  Jobr                                0x00000001043ee5e7 main + 55
>       50  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109b9ad81 start + 1
>       51  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Comment: Please update your question with *your* relevant code. Point out the exact line causing the error.

Comment: @maddy I had put in the link to the sample code I used but I've now added my exact code.

Comment: Use a breakpoint and check if the delegate and dataSource settings are being called(`if (tableView != nil) {`)

Comment: @Xcoder Yes I checked that already.  They are being set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431013/tableviewnumberofrowsinsection-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: @Cristik It is not a duplicate I have implemented the method - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section //(in swift of course).

Comment: In the duplicate, the OP provides the whole error message(with the "reason:"). Do you mind doing so?

Comment: @Xcoder I've added the whole error message.

Comment: @bhartsb Let me know if my answer worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

In the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614931-tableview), the tableView `numberOfRowsInSection` method is a **data source** method, not a delegate method.

Therefore, you need to create a new extension and move the `numberOfRowsInSection` method inside of it:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.tableView(tableView,numberOfRowsInSection:section)
    }
}
```